# cannot access google drive backup folder or my apps backup programatically

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

i am new to android , working on google drive, unable to access or read my appDataFolder on my google drive account. used:

```
File fileTemp =  mService.files().get("appDataFolder").execute();
```

How to access my whatsapp or my other apps backup on my google drive programatically?

Comment: Hi james, any ref. to this ques.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, you may want to first try requesting the `SCOPE_APPFOLDER` scope as part of your [authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api).

Then, after retrieving the App Folder by using the `DriveApi.getAppFolder` method, check if your file or folder is in the App Folder by retrieving its metadata. The [`Metadata.isInAppFolder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Metadata#isInAppFolder()) method returns `true` if the file or folder is in the App Folder.

See [Storing Application Data](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) for more information.